# Exception when search by null value in elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, chewy-gem

I am using elasticsearch to search some records in my application.

```
filtered: {
            query: {
                query_string: {
                    query: "*#{term}*",
                    fields: ["name"]
                }
            },
            filter: {
                bool: {
                    must: [
                        {term: {store_id: store_id}},
                        {match: {dealer: dealer}}
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```

When some param is not present and nil value is passed for `store_id` and `dealer`. Ii gives following error: `{"type":"query_parsing_exception","reason":"No text specified for text query"`
I want if `store_id` or `dealer` is nil then it should display all result matching with query. Is it possible in elasticsearch ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that you cannot do it with match or term query.

You could use wildcard or regexp query to enable wildcard search, but what I'd suggest you is to handle this in your application.

ie, when your enduser fills the input "store_id" or "dealer", you append the must clause of your query with the value.
Otherwise, you don't, and you'll get a search over the whole index.